# How to store waypoints efficiently

Tags: c++, mysql, path-finding

i have a game with a very large map, and i need to store a *lot* of waypoints (millions, if not billions) to then use them for pathfinding using the A* algorithm.

What i need:

1. Efficient way to store a lot of them
2. Fast way to access them directly for A* algorithm.

At first i thought to use a simple vector, but this would use all the available memory soon.
Then i thought i should use mysql, this maybe it's a good idea as i can query the database for an area of waypoints.

The big problem is that for A* i need to access the waypoints as fast as possible, so maybe i need an unique ID per waypoint.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Any clues on magnitude requirements of the wp extreme values?

Comment: Do you intend to fill the map with points in a regular grid, then download the grid and perform A* over it? Actually making an object for each node on the grid, regardless of whether it's empty, is a naive implementation… but compressing a mostly-empty grid shouldn't be hard, either.

Comment: I like the idea of storing waypoints in a MSQL database so you can access them directly. That's very out-of-the-box thinking. I'm not sure whether it's a good idea, but it had never occurred to me that if pointers and references are to indirect, a database would be the way to go.

Comment: @WhozCraig i can't understand this, sorry, i'm not so specialized in PathFinding

Comment: @Roberto honestly I'm thinking the same as Kerrek right about now. Not necessarily about MSSQL, but more about databasing them. If you really reach the billions and are potentially crunched for memory (at at 8-bytes-per minimum, I can totally see that happening, a DB backend of some sort might be a pretty tight alternative. Not necessarily blistering in performance, but logical and scalable. I'd  use fixed records and the fastest f'ing small-foot DB I could, but its really an interesting thought.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider going slightly lower-level by managing your memory yourself --- calling `new` and `delete` explicitly for every node of your graph; and referencing your nodes by memory address. If you are worried about allocating a lot of small chunks of memory, you can consider using [tcmalloc](http://goog-perftools.sourceforge.net/doc/tcmalloc.html) library.

The nodes should contain adjacency lists. If the graph is static, I would suggest storing the adjacency in a dynamically created array in each node, which size matches exactly the number of neighbors. If the number of neighbors can change over time, `std::vector` may be the next best thing.

---

Note: I assume the graph is irregular. For regular graphs (e.g. grid as pointed out by Potatoswatter) the location of the nodes can be learned implicitly.

Comment: The graph should be regular (a grid)